# needsDisplay triggering infinite drawRect loop

Tags: cocoa, events, swift, nsview

[Whole app for context](https://gist.github.com/jondavidjohn/8e246c28cf6b6bf66d2c)

It seems that in setting `needsDisplay` in this [`mouseUp`](https://gist.github.com/jondavidjohn/8e246c28cf6b6bf66d2c#file-app-swift-L168-L178) handler, is triggering a never ending cascade of drawing and I'm not sure why...

[image]

The desired effect is that once the `mouseUp` changes the button's `mode` property, that when the `drawRect` happens, the button's icon would simply change from [the red circle](https://gist.github.com/jondavidjohn/8e246c28cf6b6bf66d2c#file-app-swift-L204-L222), to [the black square](https://gist.github.com/jondavidjohn/8e246c28cf6b6bf66d2c#file-app-swift-L224-L236) **without** the cascading drawing that is shown in the gif above.

I've narrowed it down a bit and can say that the cause is that [the rect.origin.x being passed to `MainView`'s `drawRect` function](https://gist.github.com/jondavidjohn/8e246c28cf6b6bf66d2c#file-app-swift-L82) incrementally gets larger and the width gets smaller, but I can't figure out **why** that is.

Comment: well I am guessing you do something in a draw method that triggers the view to be redisplayed, or you start a timer that does.

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yeah, maybe because I'm assigning new frames for the child views in drawRect?  Trying to figure out what is continually re-triggering `needDisplay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was happening because I was assigning new frames to the subviews in an attempt to correctly calculate resizes...  This was triggering the draw loop because I was calculating that and assigning them within the `drawRect`.

Turns out there is an override to specifically handle view resize events.

[`resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:)

Changing the relevant code from something like

```
override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.1, alpha: 1).setFill()
    NSRectFill(rect)

    let mbFrame = NSMakeRect(
        rect.size.width / 2 - (45 / 2),
        8,
        49,
        49
    )
    mainBtn.frame = mbFrame
}
```

To

```
override func resizeSubviewsWithOldSize(oldSize: NSSize) {
    let mbFrame = NSMakeRect(
        self.frame.size.width / 2 - (45 / 2),
        8,
        49,
        49
    )
    mainBtn.frame = mbFrame
}

override func drawRect(rect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    NSColor(calibratedWhite: 0.1, alpha: 1).setFill()
    NSRectFill(rect)
}
```

Made it all play nice.